# Javascript if statement better

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, filter

I'm playing around with Django/Vue but I'm a noobie in programming and especially Javascript. I want to do some filtering in my SPA - everything works but I know it's not the correct way doing it.

The below code is what I have now but it's static. I would like to have it dynamic as the length of "this.myproductfamilieslisting" can change.

Can anyone guide me?

Thanks!!

```
                for (let x = 0; x < item.productfamily.length; x++){
                if (item.productfamily[x].productfamily == this.myproductfamilieslisting[0] || item.productfamily[x].productfamily == this.myproductfamilieslisting[1] || item.productfamily[x].productfamily == this.myproductfamilieslisting[2] || item.productfamily[x].productfamily == this.myproductfamilieslisting[3] ) {
                    resultproductfamily = item.productfamily[x].productfamily == this.myproductfamilieslisting[0] || item.productfamily[x].productfamily == this.myproductfamilieslisting[1] || item.productfamily[x].productfamily == this.myproductfamilieslisting[2] || item.productfamily[x].productfamily == this.myproductfamilieslisting[3]
                }
            }
```

Comment: You basically have two lists and you want to do something if anything in list a is also in list b?

Comment: what are you expecting to store in `resultproductfamily`? At the moment it is storing a boolean but I don't understand why you are doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner using `Array#includes`

```
...
var listing = this.myproductfamilieslisting;
var family = item.productfamily[x].productfamily;

if (listing.includes(family)) {
  // DO WHATEVER
}
```

Comment: Marks as answer if satisfactory.